# Pandas Dataframe automatically renames duplicate columns name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 10 columns and 160 rows. Column names are based on month and year for e.g Jun'17, July'17, Mar'18 etc.
However in excel some columns are repeating like Jun'17 two times
When I import them to pandas dataframe it renames duplicate columns to Jun'17 and Jun'17.1

This '.1' is extra and disturbing my whole calculation.

Comment: That is a pandas limitation. All column names must be unique. You can choose what to rename them to in the constructor / pd.read_csv function if you wish.

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful but can you be more specific on what to write in constructor?

Comment: The constructor is what makes the dataframe - the import statement

Comment: @AliasgherNooruddin what would be your desired output? do you want to keep the same duplicated name?

Comment: if you have 10 columns, why are they repeating. I had similar problem, but i just reorganized my data to put every single row under one column, e.g. column "May 2018" -> rows ("net income", "EBIT", etc..)

Comment: The question is not clear. What are you looking for? Are you just complaining? Just use the indexes or an appropriate function to parse the column names (or ask how to do that).

Comment: Yes I want to keep the same duplicate names @joe

Comment: Columns are repeating because values are changing for that column so new values must be added to the new column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think it is a good idea have more columns with the same name, and i wouldnt suggest this, but if you want to go with that, you can do in this way:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {"Jun'17.1":"Jun'17"})
```

To access to the 2 different columns then do in this way:

```
df["Jun'17"].iloc[:,0]
df["Jun'17"].iloc[:,1]
```