# Dealing with Merged Column Cells of Excel with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis

I need help with an Excel parsing issue with Pandas. I have an Excel table like this:

```
|Student ID|x_1|x_2|xyz_123|
|6677889955|3  |4  |A|B| |D|
|0987654321|1  |4  |A| |C|3|
|1324689764|2  |2  |A|5|C| |
```

But, it is parsed as dataframe like this:

```
|Student ID|x_1|x_2|xyz_123|Unnamed:4|Unnamed:5|Unnamed:6|
|6677889955|3  |4  |A      |B        |         |D        |
|0987654321|1  |4  |A      |         |C        |3        |
|1324689764|2  |2  |A      |5        |C        |         |
```

As you can see, I have a one big merged column cell that has varying number of cells under that column. I need to parse this table to Pandas, but the rest of merged column cell is names as "Unnamed:x".

I have tried fillna() method to fill the unnamed columns with the name of the main merged cell, but it only merged all the rows, except the main column header row. I would really appreciate any help that I can get. Thanks to anyone that helps, in advance.

Comment: Not a good idea to have multiple columns with the same name: however, this answer may provide you with what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188883/pandas-dataframe-automatically-renames-duplicate-columns-name#:~:text=That%20is%20a%20pandas%20limitation,read_csv%20function%20if%20you%20wish.

Comment: Multiindex not considered?

Comment: If you can share the excel file; also kindly add the expected output dataframe